# Пример ffmpeg воспроизведение файла. Вместо звука трески и шум при воспроизведении

Tags: аудио, ffmpeg

Ребята помогите с проблемой уже всю голову сломал не могу разобраться.
Пытаюсь запустить простенький пример воспроизведения видеофайла (пока без синхронизации) вот [отсюда](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial03.c). Видео - нормально воспроизводится, вместо звука трески и шумы, хотя написано что должен играть как положено.....
Никак не могу понять с чем это связано.

версия `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers  
  built with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)  
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --enable-ffplay --  enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --disable-nvenc  
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100  
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101  
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100  
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100  
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100  
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100  
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100  
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум два нюанса, которые могут оказаться (предоставьте файл "проблемный") существенными:

- Audio процессинг сделан в отдельном потоке, тогда как видео - в том же. Хоть аудио данных меньше, но больше критичность к их своевременному непоступлению при проигрывании. Вынесите обработку видео в свой поток тоже.
- Я вижу, что вы настраивается SDL на формат семпла Signed 16bit, при этом остальные данные берутся из кодека. А вы точно уверены, что после декодирования аудио-семпла он у вас S16? И всегда так будет? Тут советов два: или более точно смотреть, что на выходе декодера и аналогично настраивать SDL, или настраивать ресемплер (swresample) и приводит любой входной формат в понятный SDL.

Ещё посмотрите код ffplay, он делает примерно то же, что хотите сделать вы и использует SDL2.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Настроил ресемплер и вуаля....вот оно)))))